# How to use Mac OSX Keymap on Windows for WebStorm or IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, settings, webstorm, keymapping, keymaps

I use WebStorm on both my Mac and Windows for work purposes.
I would like to know if it is possible to use the MAC OSX keymap on Windows.

On windows if you load the MAC OSX keymap the mappings don't seem to line up correctly. For instance I see the character `Meta` being used, however Windows doesn't seem to properly map that character.

I also would like to note I am using a Mac keyboard on the Windows PC.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How does <kbd>Cmd</kbd> (<kbd>Meta</kbd>) key map to your Windows keys?

You can get the [full Mac keymap XML](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-resources/src/keymaps/Mac%20OS%20X%2010.5+.xml) file and replace `meta` with whatever key it is on Windows. Some keys may not work or you may get conflicting mappings.

There is no easy and straightforward way that will work out of the box.

On Mac keymap is using <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Meta</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifiers. This cannot be directly mapped to only 3 modifiers you have on Windows (<kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>). You [can't use <kbd>Win</kbd> as the modifier](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144702) by default.

Also, a lot of the combinations with <kbd>Win</kbd> would be already taken by the OS (and the only way to disable these default mappings is via [registry modification](http://www.askvg.com/tip-how-to-disable-all-win-keyboard-shortcuts-hotkeys-in-windows/)).

You are welcome to give it a try as [there is a workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144702#comment=27-1491339) to make <kbd>Win</kbd> work as a modifier in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Thank you, where do I add the .xml file on windows once I have created the mapping.

Comment: The file is placed in [CONFIG](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519)`/keymaps` directory. Make sure IDE is not running at this moment.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to create another mapping template that works for standard Windows keyboards? (so that mappings are similar to Mac) I suggest to use Caps Lock for the extra Mac key (Command or Control). Caps Lock is a key that people seldom use anyway. The current templates simply don't function for this use case (Mac mapping on Windows keyboard), and I think it's an important use case.

Comment: I have a mac keyboard and a Windows machine, how do I go about using mac shortcuts on a Windows machine?

Comment: @CrazyCoder thank you for the answer. Can IntelliJ just introduce a keymap for macOS that will not use Meta/CMD? To make it similar to Windows/Linux

Comment: Why keymap differs so much? One thing - META keys, but another - keymaps. For example: Refactor this — Ctrl + Alt + Shift +T vs Ctrl + T, or Select next occurrence — Alt + J vs Ctrl + G

Comment: If Windows has fewer modifiers would it not make sense to bring the windows keymaps over to Mac instead?

Answer (score 6):

There is a third party plugin by [samvtrran](https://github.com/samvtran) that solve that: [macOS For All](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13968-macos-for-all)

Here is the plugin description:

> A keymap for Windows and Linux (and macOS if you really want!) that
> rebinds common macOS 10.5+ shortcuts to non-Command keys. Some
> shortcuts aren't 1:1 replacements of modifier keys, so please check
> the key updates table.
>
> If you notice any conflicting shortcuts or have a suggestion for a new
> keybinding, please open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: This works great! While the replacements aren't 1:1, they're really well thought out and intuitive!

Answer (score 4):

On Windows go to `file > settings > keymap` and in the `keymaps` dropdown select `default` and the `meta` (aka `cmd`) key will be replaced by `ctrl`.