# IntelliJ keymap for Windows that equals MacOS shortcuts

Tags: windows, macos, intellij-idea

Since I'm coding on both Windows and on MacOS, I'm looking for an IntelliJ keymap that uses the same order of keys for all of its actions.

- Ctrl on Windows should be Ctrl on MacOS
- Win on Windows should be Alt on MacOS
- Alt on Windows should be Cmd on MacOS

To explain this a bit more precise. When there's a shortcut Cmd+C on MacOS, I want that shortcut to be Alt+C on Windows.

Is there such a keymap?

Comment: See the [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42422764/104891). You can't reliably use Win key on Windows for keyboard shortcuts in IntelliJ IDEA, but there is a hack to make it work. You will have to create the keymap yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Mac OSX Keymap on Windows for WebStorm or IntelliJ IDEA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422318/how-to-use-mac-osx-keymap-on-windows-for-webstorm-or-intellij-idea)